# HttpServletResponse from POJO using spring

Tags: java, spring, httpresponse, pojo

[Source](http://techdive.in/solutions/how-get-httpservletrequest-object-pojo-class-spring-framework)

**How to get HttpServletRequest Object in a POJO Class in Spring Framework?**

```
public class SimplePOJO {

//Receive Request 
ServletRequestAttributes servReq= (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest req = servReq.getRequest(); 

//Want to send HttpServletResponse 

}
```

can we send **HttpServletResponse** from the same POJO ? like above

Comment: You're asking about getting the `response` - `HttpServletResponse` - not request, right?

Comment: why didn't you insert your code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a HttpServletRequest object in any spring bean but you have to scope your bean to request as follow.

```
<bean id="simplePOJOBean" class="SimplePOJO" scope="request"/>


 public class SimplePOJO {

 private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

 //Just use the autowired request object


 }
```

It is not possible to get a http response object in the service layer, however you can do it other way. This stuff has been explained here well http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/06/injecting-httpservletresponse-into-spring-mvc-request-scoped-interceptors/

Comment: He's asking about the `response` - `HttpServletResponse`. Not request.